# Waterfall value (get value from previous row to populate the next one) with arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am traying to resolve this but I think my brain is frozen and I cant find a solution online because I dont know how to correctly describe what I want to be able to find the answer.

So, for example I have this in google sheets,

| Level | Category 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Car |
| 2 | Hatchback |
| 2 | Coupe |
| 2 | Convertible |
| 1 | Moto |
| 2 | Cruiser |
| 2 | Scooter |

And I want this with the last column automatically expended using arrayformula:

| Level | Category 2 | Category 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | Car |
| 2 | Hatchback | Car |
| 2 | Coupe | Car |
| 2 | Convertible | Car |
| 1 | Moto | Moto |
| 2 | Cruiser | Moto |
| 2 | Scooter | Moto |

I want that in column C it will give me the corresponding text to number "1" and then for the rest of the rows it will give me the previous row until it find the next "1"

I was trying with filter, row, ifs but it is not working and my brain is melting, I was able to do that but not using arrayformula, tried to transform to arrayformula but it did not work. I want it to populate automatically. Can I have some help please? (Also I dont like to use query so something that dont use that pls)

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=scan(,A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,if(c=1,offset(c,,1),a)))
```

[image]

[***How Scan() works***](https://youtu.be/Fuf3U9LCOoQ)

---

***Alternate using vlookup()***

```js
=arrayformula(let(Δ,match(,0/(A:A<>"")), Σ,A2:index(A:A,Δ), Λ,if(row(Σ)*Σ=row(Σ),row(Σ),),
 vlookup(row(Σ),{Λ,B2:index(B:B,Δ)},2,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there another way? I have a lot of data and it will be pretty heavy to use lambda

Comment: alternate formula updated

Comment: This works thank you! Only that its a very complicated formula for my not very advanced knowledge, I will need to try to understand it

Comment: the simplest would be to use this in **C2** and drag it down: `=xlookup(1,A$2:A2,B$2:B2,,,-1)`

Comment: yes, I wanted to be it automatic so will be using the previous one (even if I dont understand it completely) the good thing is that now I know about a new function, the LET function, I will be using this in other formulas too